# Create an array during a while

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `while` that loops in my sql results.

```
while ($var = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
  $data1 = $var['data1'];
  $data2 = $var['data2'];
  $data3 = $var['data3'];
}
```

How can I create a `multidimensional array` with these values ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The mysql library you use is deprecated and will be removed. If you switch to PDO, you can use the [PDOStatement::fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method, which does exactly what you want.

If you insist on using the mysql library, you can do something like this:

```
$array= array();
while ($array[] = mysql_fetch_array ($result));
```

It will generate an array, where each item represents a row. Each item is itself an array containing row data.